# How to draw objects that can be dragged and droped on the screen using pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to draw 5 rectangles all of which I can drag and drop across the screen. I am using pygame. I managed to draw 1 rectangle that I can drag and drop but I can't do it with 5. This is my code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from random import randint


SCREEN_WIDTH = 1024
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 768

BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED   = (255,   0,   0)
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

pygame.display.set_caption("Moving circles")

rectangle = pygame.rect.Rect(20,20, 17, 17)
rectangle_draging = False


clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:            
                if rectangle.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    rectangle_draging = True
                    mouse_x, mouse_y = event.pos
                    offset_x = rectangle.x - mouse_x
                    offset_y = rectangle.y - mouse_y

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if event.button == 1:            
                rectangle_draging = False

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            if rectangle_draging:
                mouse_x, mouse_y = event.pos
                rectangle.x = mouse_x + offset_x
                rectangle.y = mouse_y + offset_y


    screen.fill(WHITE)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, rectangle)

    pygame.display.flip()

clock.tick(FPS)


pygame.quit()
```

I guess this is the most important part:

```
  pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, rectangle)
```

Every time I try drawing 5 of them I can't drag any of them. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Can you show one of the failed efforts? I suspect you may be trying to reuse the `rectangle` variable...

Comment: @GlennRogers yes I did try that cause I had no idea how to do it any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list of rectangles and a `selected_rect` variable which points to the currently selected rect. In the event loop check if one of the rects collides with the event.pos, then set the `selected_rect` to the rect under the mouse cursor and move it.

I'm using a `pygame.math.Vector2` for the `offset` to save a few lines in the example.

```
import sys
import pygame as pg
from pygame.math import Vector2


pg.init()

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED   = (255,   0,   0)

screen = pg.display.set_mode((1024, 768))

selected_rect = None  # Currently selected rectangle.
rectangles = []
for y in range(5):
    rectangles.append(pg.Rect(20, 30*y, 17, 17))
# As a list comprehension.
# rectangles = [pg.Rect(20, 30*y, 17, 17) for y in range(5)]

clock = pg.time.Clock()
running = True

while running:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                for rectangle in rectangles:
                    if rectangle.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        offset = Vector2(rectangle.topleft) - event.pos
                        selected_rect = rectangle
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if event.button == 1:
                selected_rect = None
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
            if selected_rect:
                selected_rect.topleft = event.pos + offset

    screen.fill(WHITE)
    for rectangle in rectangles:
        pg.draw.rect(screen, RED, rectangle)

    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)

pg.quit()
sys.exit()
```